# Receive button click event in fragment subclass

Tags: android

I currently add a fragment to my activity. The fragment has a LinearLayout with a button on it. When the button is clicked however, the click event is sent to the activity and not the fragment. How can I receive the button click event in the fragment rather than the activity?

Comment: If you use the `onClick` attribute then the method needs to be indeed in the activity. You could however, write the same method in your fragment and call that from the activity method(after finding the fragment instance). But you'd be better off just setting a `OnClickListener` manually.

Comment: > you need to read more about fragment activity
> > [what is fragment](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html)?
> > [Fragment activity how they work](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html)?
> > [Fragment tutorial](http://marakana.com/s/post/1250/android_fragments_tutorial)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the onclick method of the button to an onclickListener inside the fragment, or to an inline on that forwards to a method on the fragment, etc.

```
Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.myButton);
b.setOnClickListener(myFragmentWhichImplementsButtonClickListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

Click event is sent to `listener` you bond to view being clicked. So it's basically irrelevant if your view is part for activity directly, or it's part of fragment. If you attach listener to your button, then that listener will be clicked **unless** your button is somehow i.e. covered by other element of the layout that "steals" the click. But you should set the listener **within** the fragment (i.e. in `onCreateView()`).